# Etiqueta envío gratuito en cada producto Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

Necesito mostrar una frase/etiqueta en cada producto con envío gratuito en **Prestashop 1.6** y trato de validar utilizando lo siguiente en el archivo **product-list.tpl**:

```
{if isset($product.additional_shipping_cost) && $product.additional_shipping_cost == 0}
<SPAN>{l s='Envío Gratuito'}
```

Pero al guardar todos los productos me los muestra con la frase de envío gratuito aunque el transportista elegido tenga costo o sea gratuito no hace distinción

También he eliminado todos los transportistas, creé uno solo con costo pero continua igual mostrandome todos los productos con envío gratuito aunque el transportista sea con costo.

Alguien podría indicarme alguna solución? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Según la sintaxis que encuentro en la [documentación de smarty](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/es/language.function.if.tpl) te faltaría cerrar la sentencia if de la siguiente manera:

```
{if isset($product.additional_shipping_cost) && $product.additional_shipping_cost == 0}
<SPAN>{l s='Envío Gratuito'}
{/if}
```

Comment: Si amigo así lo tengo cerrado, no lo puse pensando en solo enfocarme en la lógica del IF. Una disculpa.

Comment: ¿Te has asegurado de que la variable que almacena los gastos de envío sea `$product.additional_shipping_cost` y no `$product.shipping_cost`? Con smarty existe una opción para hacer debug en prestashop y ver todas las variables que manejaba cada página y sus valores. Se puede activar desde el fichero `config/smarty.config.inc.php` descomentando la línea: `//$smarty->debugging = true;`. Una vez descomentes esa línea aparecerá el modo debug al refrescar la página en el navegador.

Comment: Intenté lo que me comentaste amigo pero no funciona. He pensado que es imposible ya que he buscado por días y no encuentro nada.